# Java Script Merge 2 not the same lenght Arrays using different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have 2 2D arrays. One with unique keys  and another where this key appears more times. 
I would like add first array by key to each corresponding array in second object.

**INPUT:**

```
arr1 = [
  { id: "one", val1: "ggg1" }, 
  { id: "two", val1: "ggg2" },
  { id: "three", val1: "ggg3" }
];

arr2 = [
  { id: "one", val2: "ggg" }, 
  { id: "two", val2: "ggg" },
  { id: "three", val2: "ggg" },
  { id: "one", val2: "ggg" }, 
  { id: "two", val2: "ggg" },
  { id: "three", val2: "ggg" }
];
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
arr3 = [
  { id: "one", val2: "ggg", val1: "ggg1" }, 
  { id: "two", val2: "ggg", val1: "ggg2" },
  { id: "three", val2: "ggg", val1: "ggg3" },
  { id: "one", val2: "ggg", val1: "ggg1" }, 
  { id: "two", val2: "ggg", val1: "ggg2" },
  { id: "three", val2: "ggg", val1: "ggg3" }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

For example

```
arr3 = arr2.map((item) => {
    return {
        ...item,
        ...arr1.find((y) => y.id === item.another_id),
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
var mergedList = _.map(arr1 , function(item){
    return _.extend(item, _.findWhere(arr2, { id: item.id }));
});
```